# tcp payload size is it one byte?

Tags: tcp

Well the tcp segment number is used to identify a byte in the byte stream. So does tcp only support a payload of size one byte only ?

Comment: Jake - You're not reading or ignoring comments left for you - can I ask you to re-read our FAQ and look at the other questions on this site as I'm not convinced there's a perfect fit going on here - you seem to ask a lot of homework-style questions and can't have used any other search systems first before asking. You've also asked 8 homework-style questions in less than 48 hours without accepting any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously, you need to re-read your TCP/IP. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol):

Sequence number (32 bits) – has a dual role:

- If the SYN flag is set, then this is the initial sequence number. The sequence number of the actual first data byte (and the acknowledged number in the corresponding ACK) are then this sequence number plus 1.
- If the SYN flag is clear, then this is the accumulated sequence number of the first data byte of this packet for the current session.

Answer (score 6):

No

Comment: Actually, it's only 7 bit. The 8th bit is a checksum...

Comment: books talk about tcp sending octets. Then what are these octets ? Arent they the payload ?

Comment: @user68350: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/index.htm

Comment: Chopper3: I know you are the man here on SF, but I'm actually going to downvote this answer because you can do better (especially a rock star like you). I know the question is kindof lame, and shows barely a minimum attempt to understand the subject matter, but you typically rise above this and provide a thorough and complete answer anyway. Honestly, I find it shameful that there are so many upvotes for an answer without even a minimum explanation. If you fix, I'll remove the dv.

Comment: You flatter me Jed, I'm actually rubbish at all this stuff. Seriously though what you may not be aware of is 'Jake's history on this site, he's been here for two days and asked 8 homework questions, he's clearly put no effort whatsoever into any of them and I'm one of those guys that thinks a lazy question does not justify a complex, time-consuming answer - it would only encourage more of the same. Totally get what you say, it's not a good answer and perhaps I'm taking his history out on him but I'm not only a human but pretty much the only active mod (until next week anyway :) )

Comment: I'd say it's a justified answer given @Chopper3's reasons in the comment above and the comment in the question. This is supposed to be a site for people to get help with their work, not homework. Or if people do want homework help at least show they're putting in effort to understanding the work. It's a little suspicious to have a large number of questions all asked at once if it's something they're working on in class. That's just my feeling, though.

Comment: Ok, given the extra info in comments I agree. Of course the best solution is to remove bogus questions like this, which has happened now, thankfully. I'll remove my downvote, but I'm not voting the answer up (and I don't think other should have either). I will upvote your comment, though. :)

Comment: Doh! I can't remove my downvote unless you edit the question.

Comment: Thanks Jed, I personally didn't want to delete it as I think that the subject matter is appropriate for here and if the question had been better I would have written a better answer - I didn't want to rob anyone of the opportunity, like I said I have my own view but others may have a different one. Oh and don't you worry about the downvote, I don't come here for that :)

Comment: @Chopper3, yes, but I don't have 30K+! I want my point back. :)

Comment: hadn't spotted I'd gone over 30 actually - wonder when that was? odd - anyway I'll go over your posts and see if I can even the balance ;)